# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState.....crash report

Tags: java, android

I get this crash report but it does not tell me what class from. Here it is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1286)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:451)
at android.app.Activity.onBackPressed(Activity.java:2123)
at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2101)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2577)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2334)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1825)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3340)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3301)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2476)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:846)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2488)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is this??